# trabalhar com imagens no sql server + asp net

Tags: sql, asp.net, mvc

galera, no meu projeto eu preciso trabalhar com upload de imagens pelo site asp.net e salvar elas no sql server, e depois eu preciso mostrar elas numa pagina como se fosse de produtos, com descriçao e etc. No sql eu salvo o campo com o tipo "image" certo? mas e no model do projeto, que tipo eu coloco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde!!! Já trabalhei com situações iguais a essa e depois de uma boa pesquisa e ponderações, tenho como ideia que basta você salvar o endereço da imagem no banco e salvar as imagens em uma pasta no servidor. Isso é uma boa prática adotada onde são levados vários pontos, como por exemplo, a performance. Apenas em casos bem específicos é recomendado o armazenamento de imagens diretamente no banco.

Agora, caso seu caso seja realmente em salvar no banco, para salvar uma imagem pode utilizar o campo blob do sql e no c# você irá utilizar um array de bytes.

Segue um link para você dar uma olhada.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-should-we-store-images-and-blob-files-in-sql-server/

Espero ter ajudado!